# Finding max among two lists in python

Tags: max

I am not getting how we will be able to find the `max()` among two list with  different no. of elements in them.
Here is an example:

```
list1=[123,'abc']
list2=[456,'bca']
```

Comment: And you want to sort it on the basis of?

Comment: Nopes after that i just want to print the max list. And also can you please let me know how it works step by step. Or may be you can take your own example.

Comment: :) I mean to ask, you want the list to be sorted on the basis of numbers (first parameter) or the alphabet list (second parameter).  Also, you can include a 'python' tag for your question.

Comment: i am not getting what you mean to say, i am just looking for print(max(list1,list2))